# Replacement for pop rocks?

Tags: pop-rocks

I'm a big Heston Blumenthal fan and I'd like to try one of his recipes, which requires pop rocks. The problem is that I live in Brazil and nobody seems to have heard about pop rocks and I really don't know where to get it. Any suggestions for a replacement?

Comment: I'd say you need to do some research among local children and find out what the things are called in Portuguese. This is a popular product, no reason why it hasn't reached Brazil yet.

Comment: www.cybercandy.com stocks them and ships worldwide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for taking your time, everyone. It turns out a visit to the candy store was all I needed. They've got the original Pop Rocks.

Answer (score 6):

The method to make them is patented, and involves highly pressurized C02. Doubtful, you'd be able to find a replacement product. Online store maybe? *shrug*

However, you could try making a cheap [home-made subsitute](http://www.instructables.com/id/Pop-Rocks/step4/Lets-get-Fizzy/). Don't think it'd be an exact duplicate, might suffice for your purposes?

Answer (score 4):

you can order them on Amazon: [http://www.amazon.com/Pop-Rocks-Units-Assorted-Flavors/dp/B003UPDBJO/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1342563858&sr=8-3&keywords=pop+rocks](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003UPDBJO).

I'm sure they will ship.

Comment: You beat me to it by a minute. Just curious, are they also that expensive when you buy them in a store?

Comment: @Mien, last time I looked, they were about the same. (not including shipping)

Comment: @Mein: I get them in a box of 8 (0.85oz total) for US$1.50 at World Market.  That price on Amazon is horrible unless the individual units are huge.  (especially considering it's likely meant for reselling)